# laravel new project_name command installing too many packages

Tags: laravel

I have an issue, when running the "laravel new *project_name*" command, I get a new laravel project alright but with way too many dependencies (I end up with 207 Mo directory). Could someone please show me how to prevent it from installing unnecessary dependencies? Thank you very much.

Comment: Those are necessary.

Comment: I fixed my problem, I re-installed Laravel and now the directory is 44 Mo. I must've messed up something during the first Laravel installation. Thanks for your input though @IGP